# Scope of dependencies in singleton Spring controllers

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-mvc, javabeans

In Spring MVC , Controllers (@Controller) are singleton.

Assume I have a dependency on a service class in a controller and the service class has a scope of prototype. 
In a scenario like this,

1. will we get different instances of the service class for two different requests coming at the same time to the controller?
2. If only once instance of service class is available for two different requests, then will the local variables defined inside the functions of service class overlap within the two requests?

Answer (score 2):

1. No. In order to construct a controller (which will be a singleton), we need an instance of the service. Every time we are demanding that service, a new object will be created. Once the controller is established (all dependencies are set), no other injections are going to happen.

Consider the example below.

Both `controller1` and `controller2` require the service as a dependency. For each controller, a new instance will be created. But they won't be changed for different requests.

```
    request1 --> controller1 --> service1
    request2 --> controller1 --> service1
    request3 --> controller1 --> service1

    request4 --> controller2 --> service2
    request5 --> controller2 --> service2
    request6 --> controller2 --> service2
```

2. I am not sure I understood you correctly. If a local variable is named the same as a service field, then it partly hides that service. Accessing by `this.serviceVariable` will resolve the issue.

Comment: Thank you @Andrew . Reg. #2,  Let us say there is a local variable called "username" in of the functions available in service 1.   When two different requests come at the same time to the same controller, will there by an conflict in using the local variable?

Comment: @Praveen, local variables are never shared between threads, so there shouldn't be any conflicts.

Comment: @Praveen, *until they don't interact with shared members